# how to get current view id and previous view id's in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

What i need to implement is something like a dynamic breadcrumb, so i decided to add the view id's in an array to throw it as an link in the respective view page. so i just wanted to know to get the previous view id's which i have visited. if    `#{view.viewId}` 
gives me the current one, how to get the previous one.. i have tried by the way which is given the below link " [Are there any JSF components for implementing breadcrumb navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809743/are-there-any-jsf-components-for-implementing-breadcrumb-navigation) "

```
<h:form id="breadcrumb">
                    <p:breadCrumb>
                        <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.Index}" action="/index?faces-redirect=true" immediate="true"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="#{view.viewId.substring(0, view.viewId.length()-6)}" url="#{view.viewId.substring(0, view.viewId.length()-6)}.jsf" ajax="false"/>

                    </p:breadCrumb>
                </h:form>
```

For which i really need to know how to retrieve the previous view id's.
if there is any other way to achieve a dynamic bread crumb is really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear, if you want to display the page *hierarchy* (this is what I would call breadcrumb navigation) or the page *history*.

If you look for the second, there are client side or server side approaches. See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417743/620338).